# XAML / C# : for each border

Tags: c#, xaml

In XAML / C# I use a lot of similar borders. They are named border1, border2, ..., border10.
At the moment my databinding looks like this:

```
border01.DataContext = myObjectList[0];
border02.DataContext = myObjectList[1];
...
border10.DataContext = myObjectList[9];
```

That is obviously quite ugly. 
How do I loop through all my borders?

How do I -for example- edit every border opacity in one loop?

Thx, Sid

Comment: You don't do this in WPF. the `DataContext` Property is ["Inherited"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753197.aspx) throughout the Visual Tree. What are you attempting to do?

Comment: I guess you're looking for an `ItemsControl`?? Post some relevant XAML and a screenshot of what you need and I can tell you the proper way to do it in WPF.

Comment: why don't you use an array for border too.

Comment: Are you setting the DataContext in order to set properties on the border?  If that's the case, you should probably be using styles instead.  Take a look at [this MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

@HighCore in commentary gave you good recommendation, that you should consider to use `ItemsControl`, which will host each border, and the items source for this `ItemsControl` will be the list of your objects `myObjectList`.

I don't know what you are trying to do, but to answer on your question I'd recommend you to use [FindName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, which you can use something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= myObjectList.Length; i++)
{
   Border border = this.FindName("border{0:00}", i + 1);
   border.Opacity = 0.5d;
}
```